# Rails Font-Awesome not displaying - Using wrong filenames

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I have a rails app that uses Font-Awesome. The icons are displaying in Development environment but not in production.

I have checked my Nginx/Passenger logs and these show the following:

`[21/Nov/2017:17:13:25 +0000] "GET /assets/back/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 1564 "https://example.com/assets/application_back-b78b545bb6d96e3f98206780079663e7d84d11a41143a57b3ab7b110feac9944.css`

I have checked in the `public/assets/back/font-awesome/` directory and all the font files are showing like `fontawesome-webfont-aa58f33f239a0fb02f5c7a6c45c043d7a9ac9a093335806694ecd6d4edc0d6a8.ttf` which is why it cannot find the files but I don't know why it is doing this

Comment: Those are the optimized/minified versions, you likely need to run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` to generate your production assets.

Comment: I’ve run that but it’s still the same

Answer (score 1):

Rails asset pipeline adds a string the end of the filename so assets can be expired from caches when they are modified. Because of this, you need to use Rails built in url helpers to make sure you reference the correct filename.

In any ERB where you reference the Font Awesome fonts try using the asset-path helper:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontawesome-webfont';
  src: url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.eot") %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix") %>') 
  format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.woff") %>') format('woff'),
  url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.ttf") %>') format('truetype');
}
```

In your SASS files you can use the asset-url helper:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontawesome-webfont';
  src: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
  src: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix")
  format('embedded-opentype'),
  asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff") format('woff'),
  asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

If you are just trying to reference the font awesome CSS file from one of your layouts, use the stylesheets helper:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "FILENAME-OF-YOUR-FA-STYLESHEET.css"
```

Here is some more reading on Rails asset pipeline and all the different helpers available: [Rails Asset Pipline Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by refactoring the assets, converting the backend CSS to SCSS and changing the `url(...)` calls to `font-url(...)` Now it calls the files correctly.